# Pull Custom Taxonomies ACF Fields to frondend

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Hey there awesome Stackoverflow peeps,

I have assigned colors to a custom taxonomy using ACF and I am trying to pull the colors of that tag to the post that I assign them to but I am not sure how to go about it. Can someone share the secret sauce?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for the ACF get_field function. Documentation on that here: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/.

The second parameter is what you'll need to pay attention to. Sounds from the question like this field is on a term of a custom taxonomy? In which case the easiest way is to pass the whole term object there like:

get_field( 'color', $term );

You can use get_field to return the value or the_field to echo it.

Comment: Thanks for this @JBoss. The answer was a bit more complicated since I had to fetch the custom taxonomy and then define its values. I ended up doing it with get_the_terms and also get_field. :)